# I'm writing a search test I got error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to run a test to search for test/controllers/boiler-parts.controller.spec.ts

```
it('should search by string', async () =\> {
const body = { search: 'nos' };
const login = await request(app.getHttpServer())
.post('/users/login')
.send({ username: mockedUser.username, password: mockedUser.password });

    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
         .post('/boiler-parts/search')
         .send(body)
         .set('Cookie', login.headers['set-cookie']);
    
    expect(response.body.rows.length).toBeLessThanOrEqual(20);
    response.body.rows.forEach((element) => {
         expect(element.name.toLowerCase()).toContain(body.search);
     });
    expect(response.body.rows).toEqual(
         expect.arrayContaining([
            {
               id: expect.any(Number),
               price: expect.any(Number),
               boiler_manufacturer: expect.any(String),
               parts_manufacturer: expect.any(String),
               vendor_code: expect.any(String),
               name: expect.any(String),
               description: expect.any(String),
               images: expect.any(String),
               in_stock: expect.any(Number),
               bestsellers: expect.any(Boolean),
               new: expect.any(Boolean),
               popularity: expect.any(Number),
               compatibility: expect.any(String),
               createdAt: expect.any(String),
               updatedAt: expect.any(String),
           },
       ]),
    );

});
```

```
I got this error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
```

expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

```
Expected: ArrayContaining [{"bestsellers": Any<Boolean>, "boiler_manufacturer": Any<String>, "compatibility": Any<String>, "createdAt": Any<String>, "description": Any<String>, "id": Any<Number>, "images": Any<String>, "in_stock": Any<Number>, "name": Any<String>, "new": Any<Boolean>, "parts_manufacturer": Any<String>, "popularity": Any<Number>, "price": Any<Number>, "updatedAt": Any<String>, "vendor_code": Any<String>}]
Received: []

    expect(element.name.toLowerCase()).toContain(body.search);
});
 expect(response.body.rows).toEqual(
                            ^
     expect.arrayContaining([
        {
           id: expect.any(Number),
```

I didn’t find a specific solution on the Internet, so I’ll be glad to see any changes.

Comment: Looks like your server responded with `rows: []`. You'd have to check that you actually sent back data from the database and is what you expect (kind of what the test is for)